# Regex for Mac address not working properly

Tags: javascript, str-replace, regex-negation, mac-address, regexp-replace

I am using javascript trying to grep everything that is NOT the mac address and remove it.
Here is an example of a string.

```
var x = "20:ce:c4:00:01:e6 VLAN_ID=0";
```

I am trying to remove the `"VLAN_ID=0"`
So the desired output would be:

```
var x ="20:ce:c4:00:01:e6"
```

I've used two different regexes for mac address:

```
const regex = /[0-9a-f]{1,2}([\\.:-])(?:[0-9a-f]{1,2}\1){4}[0-9a-f]+/;
const regex2 = /([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})|([0-9a-fA-F]{4}\\.[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\\.[0-9a-fA-F]{4})+/;
```

I've tried playing around with the ^ but no luck
Using `x = x.replace(regex2, "");`
It replaces everything that is the mac address leaving me with the output `VLAN_ID=0`

Comment: Is the space consistently there and in the same place?

Comment: IF the space is always there you can simply split on that and use the first part.

Comment: Instead of removing stuff that doesn’t match, consider extracting stuff that does match.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Comment: i tried to use something like this const regex3 = /[.*\s]/; and have played with the ^ but still no luck

Comment: Not sure why you are replacing the value you want to keep? What about something like `x.replace(/\s.+$/,'')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the result by accessing the first match like so:

```js
var x = "20:ce:c4:00:01:e6 VLAN_ID=0";
const regex2 = /([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})|([0-9a-fA-F]{4}\\.[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\\.[0-9a-fA-F]{4})+/;
x = x.match(regex2)[0];
console.log(x)
```